# HTML slideshow doesn´t run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to insert some kind of a slideshow in a web page, but it just piles up images and it doesn´t work. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Here´s the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>#</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css">-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.carousel-inner img {
width:100%;
}
</style>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

 </head>
 <body>
 <!-- start header -->
 <div class="header_bg">
 <div class="wrap">
    <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">

    </div>
    <div class="h_right">
        <br></br><ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="index.html" >#</a></li>
            <li><a href="Empresa.html">#</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="destaques.html">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="marcas.html">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactos.html">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.html">#</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
            <form>
                <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Enter your search term..." type="text" value="" name="search" id="search">
                <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="">
                <span class="sb-icon-search"></span>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
        <script src="js/uisearch.js"></script>
        <script>
            new UISearch( document.getElementById( 'sb-search' ) );
        </script>
        <!-- start smart_nav * -->
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="index.html">#</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="Empresa.html">#</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="marcas.html">#</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="contactos.html">#</a></li>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/responsive.menu.js"></script>
        <!-- end smart_nav * -->
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="header_btm">
    <div class="h_left">
        <h1><img src="images/manuelazevedoesergiosantoslda.png"></img></a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="soc_icons">
        <h2></h2>
            <br></br><ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icon4_h.png"/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icon5_h.png"/></a></li>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </ul>   
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <!-- start main -->

  <div class="row-fluid"  >

   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item">
                <img src="images/DESTAQUE_Herma.jpg" alt="">

              </div>

              <div class="item">
                <img src="images/DESTAQUE_Primo.jpg" alt="">
              </div>

              <div class="item">
                <img src="images/DESTAQUE_Easy Dò.jpg" alt="">

              </div>

              <div class="item active">
                <img src="images/DESTAQUE_Acryl.jpg" alt="">

              </div>

            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
          </div>

   <!--End Of Carosuel Slide show-->

    </div>  
    <div class="footer">
    <div class="span_of_4">
        <div class="span1_of_4">
            <h4>Sobre nós</h4>
            <p>#</p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <span></span>
            <p class="top"></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <div class="f_icons">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="icon4" href="#"></a></li>
                    <li><a class="icon5" href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span1_of_4">
            <h4>#</h4>
            <p>#</p>
        </div>
        <div class="span1_of_4">
            <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fmass.lda&width=600&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=true&header=true&height=435" scrolling="yes" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:600px; height:360px; background: white; float:left; " allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_top">
        <div class="f_nav1">
            <ul>
                <!--<li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>-->
                <!--<li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>-->
                <!--<li><a href="marcas.html">marcas</a></li>-->
                <li><a href="contactos.html">Politica de Privacidade e de Protecção de dados pessoais da MASS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="copy">

        </div>-->
        <div class="clear"></div>
     </div>
    <!--script-->       
    </body>
     </html>
```

I have tried some other ways but this is the most close I´ve got to getting it to work...

Comment: Make sure all your imports are correct.

Comment: Try adding data-ride="carousel" attribute  in id="myCarousel" DIV.

Answer (score 0):

May be that's because of jquery versions problem as Bootstrap carousel not working for higher versions of jQuery.

I have same problem. It can be fixed with latest bootstrap js.

Use

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

It can fix your problem.

Replace

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
```

with

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

AND

replace

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
```

with

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
```

If this doesn't fix your problem read comments at [CAROUSEL ISSUE](https://www.drupal.org/node/2196245) for more details.

**EDIT**

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/5hddugjw/7/)

Comment: is it possible that is something in my css thats keeping the slideshow to run? it still doesnt work :\

Comment: Update question with my given changes so i can check it and help you

Answer (score -1):

Move this:

before body end tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The bootstrap documentation shows it in the `<head>`, so I have trouble believing that has a DOM ordering problem baked into it. If any of the other scripts in the page depend on it, then moving it after will certainly break them and make things worse.

Comment: You are wrong. Read documentation again, carefully. Bootstrap.min.js is not bootstrap.min.css and must be right before </body>.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the documentation which shows it next to a `<link>` — https://www.evernote.com/l/AANHSW1mjqdL1KhMiWaJ1ZjUM34ipVulPxM — and a `<link>` must go in the `<head>`.

Comment: Open getbootstrap.com, go to Getting started and find Basic template.

Comment: All that shows if that (so long as no other script you use before it depends on it) you *can* put it at the end. Other documentation on the same page shows that you *can* put it in the head. Thus there is no reason to suggest that moving it to the end could fix the problem the OP is having.

Comment: In "other documentation on the same page" is no one word about putting it to the head. Basic template and all examples on that page have bootstrap.min.js before body end.

Comment: I refer you back to my previous comment in which I linked to a screenshot of that page showing it in the head.

Comment: Your screenshot shows what you must put to your code, not where. So, read documentation again. And this time read whole Getting Started page, especially Basic Template and Examples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103195/discussion-between-vladislavladicky-and-quentin).

Comment: "Your screenshot shows what you must put to your code, not where" — See my previous comment. `<link>` elements are only allowed in the `<head>`, thus that code example must go in the `<head>`.

Comment: This is really weird :) Again, your screenshot only shows WHAT you must put to your code, not WHERE. And again, read WHOLE Getting Started page.

Comment: It shows the script tag next to the link tag. Link tags can only go in one place. Thus you can infer that it is perfectly fine to put the link that in the place that it is allowed (the head) and the script tag next to it.

Comment: If you're really convinced that logic is faulty (it isn't), how about you construct a couple of test cases which are identical except for the position of the script tag for the bootstrap.js file, one that works and one that doesn't.